# In ElasticSearch - How can we sort a text field alphabetically?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

We hit an odd behaviour in ElasticSearch (ES). We have a database of companies, and wanted to sort results by company name (which is a field of type `text`). This failed, because ES sorted on *any* word in the name. So e.g. the name "Zoo on a Bus" would come out near the top, as it contains "a" which gets sorted highly.

As a work-around solution, we're using a type `keyword` field to sort.

Is there a better solution? A parameter we could pass into sort that would make it work alphabetically on the whole field.

Comment: No. You need to make sure the mapping you have for that field keeps the field the way you wanted it to be. To make it easier you can also use [sub-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/multi-fields.html) to define the `keyword` version of that field. That's the standard way for this kind of requests. The docs link I provided even show an example of exactly what I meant.